# Trigonometry Question - find the width of the river and height of the post

Tags: trigonometry

A river running due east has straight parallel banks. A vertical post stands with its base, $P$, on the north side of the river. On the south bank are two surveyors, $A$ who is to the east and $B$ who is to the west of the post. $A$ and $B$ are at a distance $2a/7$ apart and the angle $APB = 150^\circ$. The angles of elevation from $A$ and $B$ of the top $Q$, of the post are $45^\circ$ and $30^\circ$. Find in terms of $a$, the width of the river and the height of the post.

Comment: Your attempt please

Comment: How did you start? What makes you  choose a certain value $ 2 a /7 ?$

Answer (score 2):

See the image of my work.
Is this correct?

[image: image of solution hand drawn on paper!]

Comment: Sorry,the pole is not on the ground. It is vertically standing normal to the ground.

Comment: Are you the same user as the one who posted the question? If you have access to both accounts, you can [merge them](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8403/announcement-new-user-merge-policy-tool). (And also you might consider registering - it would make using this site a bit easier for you.)